# How to make a Batch file store more than one values in a file

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo

I have a problem that when i want the batch file to make text inside of a file it's don't work here what i tried :

```
@echo off
if exist My.file (
echo hey >file.txt
echo hello >file.txt
echo yooo >file.txt
)
```

When i run it it's don't even make a file called file.txt it's just open and close it self, any one knows any solution ? and thanks.

Comment: I guess `My.file` doesn't exist. Did you try creating it before running your batch file?

Comment: Yes it's exists but the the values inside the parentheses don't work (it's don't create a file called `file.txt`and inside it a text "hey hello yooo").

Comment: `>` overwrites the contents. If you want to append text to the file, use `>>` instead.

Comment: Yes but the inside parenthese commands don't work why ?

Comment: Works for me on Windows 7. Does file `file.txt` get created, or not? If it does, what does it contain?

Comment: Be aware that your `If Exist` statement is relative only to the current directory? _not anywhere within your available drives_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way :

```
@echo off
(
echo hey
echo hello
echo yooo
) >myFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way is:

```
@echo off
if exist Myfile.txt (goto end) else (goto write)
:write
echo hello > file.txt
echo how are you? >>file.txt
:end
```

When you use only a `>` it's overwriting all content of `file.txt`, instead `>>` add content to the end of file.

Comment: Why `if exist Myfile.txt (goto end) else (goto write)` with the label line `:write` and not simply `if exist Myfile.txt goto end` or even easier `if exist Myfile.txt goto :EOF` and also no label line `:end`? A jump with command __GOTO__ to next line can be always omitted.

Comment: Yeah i also thinked about this but if i tried the parenthese it will not work?

Comment: I wrote a `goto write` for letting you see that's possible to control program flow with gotos. Pleased that you found your answer :)